# Returning a message instead a error in case of opening a excel workbook with wrong filename

Tags: excel, vba

Inside an excel macro I have a command that opens an external workbook:

```
 Workbooks.Open (directory & filename), ReadOnly:=True
```

I want that in the case the filename does not exist or has a different name from the specified in the macro, to present a message box with a customized message to the user (i.e. "the filename does not exist or has a different name"), instead the defined application error:

"`Runtime error 1004... Microsoft Excel cannot access...."

How can I archieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for the existence of the file by using **Dir()**

```
Sub OpenTester()
    Dim v As String
    directory = "C:\TestFolder\"
    fiilename = "ABZ.xls"
    v = directory & fiilename

    If Dir(v) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Warning Will Robinson, warning!"
    Else
        Workbooks.Open (v), ReadOnly:=True
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
Sub OpenFileSub()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Workbooks.Open (directory & Filename), ReadOnly:=True
    On Error GoTo 0

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "the filename does not exist or has a different name"

End Sub
```